# Rails Fixtures with BCrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures, bcrypt

I'm having a problem with fixtures for BCrypt password:
my `User` model is both setup with `has_secure_password` and `validates_presence_of :password`.

The point is that BCrypt uses `password` and `password_confirmation` but in the schema there is only the `password_digest` field.

The fixture is complaining that the `password` field does not exists.

How can I avoid this?

Thank you

Comment: can you post your schema?

Comment: ...and maybe show us the fixture that isn't working.  Sorry for making you do so much work but it makes it a lot easier for us to help if we can see stuff like code and actual error messages (complaints).

Answer (score 27):

Apparently for performance reasons fixtures are being pushed to the database directly. That means that instead of `password:` you need `password_digest:` in your fixtures:

```
test_user:
  email: "tester@testing.net"
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('testpassword', cost: 5) %>
```

when using bcrypt based passwords with `has_secure_password`. As mentioned in the comments `cost` argument is optional. If you don't use it a sensible default will be used.

Update: in Rails 6 bcrypt is not available by default and needs to be explicitly added/required

Comment: `cost` is optional, so `BCrypt::Password.create('password')` works

Comment: @Dorian - yes, it does. I prefer setting the value explicitly though. Saves me remembering what the default is and wondering whether it is optimised for security or efficiency ;-)

Comment: In Rails 6, you need to ensure you add `bcrypt` to your Gemfile first.

Comment: I had to add `<% require 'bcrypt' %>` to the top of the fixture file to make it work.

Answer (score -3):

I solved this problem with setup function on model test.
We can define objects in setup and use it through the test file.

```
def setup
    @user = User.new
    @user.name = 'Brunoid'
    @user.email = 'brunoid@localhost'
    @user.phone = '(01)2345-6789'
    @user.cpf = '123.456.789-10'
    @user.password = 'segamastersystem'
    @user.password_confirmation = 'segamastersystem'
    @user.card = Card.first
end

test 'must validate' do
    assert @user.valid?
end
...
```