# How to reference user password in Rails testing fixture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Surely this is asked and answered, but I cannot find an answer.

In rails, I have a typical setup with a users model.  Passwords are not stored.  Instead, I have a password_hash.  I want to write a battery of tests for a controller, and that includes logging in.  So I need to programmatically log in with typical login data, `username` and `password`.  How do I store that in a fixture and then refer to it?  Certainly I can create a fixture like

```
adam:
  username: 'adam'
  password_hash: '0e18f44c1fec03ec4083422cb58ba6a09ac4fb2a'
```

but that leaves me with no way to refer to the password programmatically---only to the password_hash.  How does one do this typically?

Edit:  Someone suggested that this question was a duplicate of [Rails Fixtures with BCrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894771/rails-fixtures-with-bcrypt).  Arguably it is, but none of the answers at that question answers the question.  The most popular answer there suggests typing in a literal for the password, `'testpassword'`, which presumably must be typed again in the tests.  The user at that question simply wanted to avoid his problem.  I explicitly want to programmatically refer to a password programmed into my fixture.  If that is not possible, then the answer is that it isn't possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Fixtures with BCrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894771/rails-fixtures-with-bcrypt)

Comment: In that question, it appears the asker has programmed in a password string, 'testpassword', and plans to explicitly type that string literal into his tests.  That seems like a bad idea to me---but necessary if there isn't a better way.

Comment: Yes, I know, it is not optimal, but one of the drawbacks of fixtures. Here is another angle on it perhaps http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/managing-login-passwords-for-capybara-with-minitest-and-rails-fixtures/

Comment: Correction (for future readers): using "'testpassword" was a suggestion made in one of the answers to the question linked above.